# RevTEX 4.1 latex class with Org-Mode

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I'm trying to get this latex class to work with org, anyone had any luck?

```
  (add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
        '("revtex"
"\\documentclass[preprint,a4paper, amsfonts, amssymb, amsmath, showkeys, nofootinbib, fleqn]{revtex4-1}
\\usepackage{amsthm}
\\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}
[EXTRA]
"
             ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
             ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
             ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
             ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph*{%s}")
             ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}")))
```

the org exporter puts the title and author commands in the preamble, while the revtex class requires them to be put in the document section, is there a way to tweak org-exporter to work with it?

Comment: Are you having a problem with it? If so, can you describe the problem? Otherwise, the question is likely to be closed as ill-defined.

Comment: You can add `#+OPTIONS: title:nil` such that org-mode will not add the `\maketitle` in the exported tex. Then you can put `\maketitle wherever you want`. You can also set `author:nil`, `date:nil`, etc.

Comment: I had forgotten about this peculiarity of `revtex` but I had to deal with it about 10 years ago, Things have changed a bit in Org mode (the understatement of the century) but the basic idea of the hack still works. See my answer. And thanks for the memories :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A long time ago, I had worked on a hack to deal with this peculiarity of `revtex` and reconstructed it for this answer (with some differences to accommodate things that have changed in Org mode, in particular the handling of titles).

The main problem as you note is that `revtex` wants the title, author and date in the body, not in the preamble where just about every *other* package wants it. That in itself is not too difficult to accomplish:

```
#+LATEX: \title{Foo}
```

will put it in the body and similarly for the others. Unfortunately, it will add it *after* the `\maketitle` and `\tableofcontents` constructs in the body, which is too late: we want it before the `\maketitle`.

The LaTeX backend (uniquely among all the backends) defines a variable `org-latex-title-command` whose default value is the string `\maketitle`. Immediately after it outputs the `\begin{document}`, it will output the value of `org-latex-title-command`. In fact, the string can be a template with placeholders like `%t` which will get substituted with the value of the `#+TITLE` keyword. Do `C-h v org-latex-title-command` to see all the placeholders that it can deal with.

So if we could redefine `org-latex-title-command` to the string `\title{%t} \maketitle`, we'd be all set: the LaTeX exporter would insert the `\title{...}` part *and* the `\maketitle` part in the body of the document, as required by `revtex`.

The way to do that is to use the `#+BIND:` keyword mechanism which allows you to define local variables in the temp buffer where the LaTeX output is constructed. The format is

```
#+BIND: variable value
```

This mechanism is considered to be something of a safety risk, so you need to explicitly allow it in your Org mode configuration:

```el
(setq org-export-allow-bind-keywords t)
```

Of course, in this case, *you* are the one setting the local variable, so you can judge whether it is unsafe, but in general, you might pick up a malicious Org mode file, so Org mode tries to be conservative in this area.

So the Org mode file would look like this at this point:

```
#+LATEX_CLASS: revtex

#+TITLE: This is the title
#+DATE: November 2, 2020

#+BIND: org-latex-title-command "\\title{%t} \\date{%D} \\maketitle"

* h1

Lorem ipsum etc.
```

Exporting to LaTeX should work and should do what you expect. Note that backslashes are doubled in the string: that's required by elisp.

There is one more wrinkle having to do with `\author` constructs. You would expect that you could add `\author{%a}` to the `#+BIND:` line and add a keyword line like this: `#+AUTHOR: A.U. Thor`,  and everything would work, but it does not: the `#+TITLE:` keyword makes the exporter produce a `title{...}` construct *in the preamble*; the `#+AUTHOR:` keyword behaves similarly. But while `revtex` seems unfazed by the existence of the `\title{...}`, it barfs on seeing `\author{...}` in the preamble. So to deal with that wrinkle, we explicitly turn off the effect of the `#AUTHOR:` keyword by turning off the `author` option in the file:

```
#+LATEX_CLASS: revtex
#+OPTIONS: author:nil

#+AUTHOR: A.U. Thor
#+TITLE: This is the title
#+DATE: November 2, 2020

#+BIND: org-latex-title-command "\\title{%t} \\author{%a} \\date{%D} \\maketitle"

* h1

Lorem ipsum etc.
```

A small extract of the resulting LaTeX file looks like this:

```
... 
\date{November 2, 2020}
\title{This is the title}
...

\begin{document}

\title{This is the title} \author{A.U. Thor} \date{(November 2, 2020)} \maketitle
\tableofcontents


\section{h1}
\label{sec:org63adbe3}

Lorem ipsum etc.
...
```

There are `\title{}` and `\date{}` constructs in the preamble but they do not matter: Org mode has already substituted their value to the places that *do* matter: the `\title{}` and `\date{}` constructs in the body, just before the `\maketitle`. Note also that even though there is no `\author{}` in the preamble (which was accomplished through the `#+OPTIONS:` setting), the one in the body also has the correct value, substituted in from the value of `#+AUTHOR:` in the Org mode file. And the proof of the pudding is that `revtex` likes the result.

Comment: Thank you!! this helps a lot

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: So is there an elegant way to insert also an abstract? It seems clumsy to put it into the line with Bind command.

Comment: Unfortunately, the place holders that are defined in `org-latex--format-spec` do not include one for `abstract`, so you would have to change the code in `ox-latex.el` to plumb the additional place holder all the way through. It's probably not that difficult (I would it do it wih an exported that's derived from the LaTeX exporter),  but it would be a fair amount of code, so not appropriate for this question. You can ask it in another question, although as usual there is no guarantee that anybody will answer it.

Comment: Actually, I'm wondering if it would be easier to add an abstract, using Org mode macros. I'll see what (if anything) comes out of that.